# What are the design advantages hash-like saving vs incremental

Tags: performance, algorithm, hash

Sites like jsfiddle and tinyurl don't save in incremental order. Is there any advantage to this?

If it's a random string or hash wouldn't this be slow because first you have to check if such an entry  already exists and if so then create a new on and repeat.

Ins't incremental so much more efficient and intuitive?

Comment: Sequential identifiers are faster to generate. But they **leak information about the temporal order of the objects identified**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving in incremental order is definitely faster.  But if your array currently has 1 billion elements, you have added 1 billion entries, and deleted 950 million entries, you might want to reuse space rather than increasing the size of your array yet again.  However much memory you have, you'll run out someday.  With a good hash table, you could save the same amount of data, comfortably, with a 100 million element array that you never need to resize.

Hash tables do require a good algorithm to develop hash codes.  If their size changes dramatically, they can either waste space or cause repeated allocations of large arrays (which can seriously annoy garbage collectors).  But they are fast, and checking for duplicates is a simple index operation.  Small numbers of duplicates can be handled in *small* linked lists, which are pretty fast.  It does help if you can guess a good initial size for your hash table.

I've always preferred "maps" or "dictionaries" based on binary trees.  They're slower, but more flexible and don't use huge arrays; memory is allocated and freed in little, manageable bits.  They can handle big swings in size/usage.  You don't need a trustworthy hash code generator.  But if you know your data, hash tables are usually better.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always possible for outsiders to distinguish a hash from a sequential key.  It's entirely possible that an application could be using some form of sequential ID internally, but encrypting it before exposing it to the outside world.  Such approaches should not generally be relied upon to provide much security from attackers who might try to "guess at" ID codes (they essentially represent "security through obscurity") but at minimum they can discourage people from taking action based upon the fact that a site seems to assign ID's in some particular fashion.  For example, a site might start with one server that uses sequential IDs, but might switch to having two servers, one of which allocates odd numbers sequentially and the other of which allocates even numbers sequentially (both servers starting somewhere past the highest number which had been allocated by the single server).  If the sequential IDs had been exposed to the outside world, it would be possible some site might have coded in an assumption that ID numbering would represent a chronological sequence.  Even something simple like multiplying an ID by some big constant (ignoring overflow), xor'ing with some value, and multiplying by some other constant would yield ID's which could be easily converted back to sequence numbers by someone who knew the method, but which would discourage any assumptions about ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Checking if an entry exists could be done in constant time if the underlying structure is a hash table, so not slow at all.